# Deploy simple NestJS microservice request-response API to WSO2

Tags: websocket, wso2, nestjs, microservices, wso2-api-manager

I'm developing a simple microservice API using NestJS microservice and TCP transport. I also use [NestJS Async API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-asyncapi) for API documentation.

```js
@AsyncApiPub({
    channel: "test/hello",
    message: {
        payload: String,
    },
})
@MessagePattern("test/hello")
async test(data: string): Promise<string> {
    return "hello world";
}
```

AsyncApi only supports Pub/Sub API so I identify request-response API as Pub.

Config:

```js
const asyncApiOptions = new AsyncApiDocumentBuilder()
    .setVersion("0.0.1")
    .setDefaultContentType("application/json")
    .addServer("Local", {
        url: `ws://localhost:3001`,
        protocol: "socket.io",
    })
    .build();

const asyncapiDocument = AsyncApiModule.createDocument(
    app,
    asyncApiOptions,
);
await AsyncApiModule.setup(microserviceDocumentPath, app, asyncapiDocument);

app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        port: 3001,
    },
});
```

Then I create new WSO2 Streaming API following [this tutorial](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/use-cases/streaming-usecase/create-streaming-api/create-a-websocket-streaming-api/), using AsyncAPI import and local endpoint.

AsyncAPI YAML definition:

```yaml
asyncapi: 2.5.0
info:
  title: ''
  description: ''
  version: 0.0.1
  contact: {}
tags: []
servers:
  Local:
    url: ws://localhost:3001
    protocol: socket.io
components:
  schemas:
    String:
      type: object
      properties: {}
defaultContentType: application/json
channels:
  test/hello:
    publish:
      message:
        payload:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/String'
        name: TestController#test
```

After subscribing to the deployed service, I can test the API by using WSO2 test curl:

```bash
wscat -c 'ws://localhost:9099/test/0.0.1/test/hello' -H 'Authorization: Bearer my_token'
```

But get not found error:

```
error: Unexpected server response: 404
```

How to deploy this API to WSO2 AM?